# How can I call React button function with other button from html which also have onclick function?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this code on React

```js
el.button(
        {
          id: 'action1',
          type: 'button',
          className: 'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block',
          onClick: this._action1,
        },
```

and I have this on my html page

```html
<button id="action2" onclick="return action2()" type="button">Action2</button>
```

I want to run the React function when I click "action2" button from my html page, is that possible?

Comment: i'm sorry what did you want? You want a button on one html page to click a button on another html page?

Comment: nvm i figure it out already